# Merge a whole language file into an array with CI

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, function, object

In my codeigniter app I have a file with 200+ phrases in a language file.

Currently I have this code:

$this->lang->load('mylanguage');

```
// Define variables
$data['title'] = $this->lang->load('title');
$data['slogan'] = $this->lang->load('slogan');
// And so on
```

I was wondering if there was a way if I could do something like this:

```
$data = $this->lang->line;
```

I understand it doesn't work like that, but perhaps some more experienced CI developers can advise the best way of doing this.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: from the docs
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html

    $this->lang->line('language_key');

Comment: I know,  but I have to manually define each variable,  I want to merge each line in my language file into one array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a third argument to the load method. If you set the third argument to TRUE, when you load the language file, it will return an array of all the language values in the file.

```
// created error file according to the CI docs
print_r($this->lang->load('error', 'english', true));

// Example output
Array
(
[error_email_missing] => You must submit an email address
[error_url_missing] => You must submit a URL
[error_username_missing] => You must submit a username
)
```

Comment: You were spot on buddy!  Nice one Matt!

Answer (score 1):

The config files you load in end up [merged](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Lang.php#L127) in to [`$this->lang->language`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Lang.php#L34). You could reach this property since it's declared public now, but i would create a subclass an the [usual way](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) and add a access function so if later its changed to protected it will still work:

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {
    public function all_line() {
        return $this->language;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a go and get back to you soon :)  Thanks for your answer mate :)